# Реальна ли минификация html на CMS Bitrix?

Tags: php, битрикс

Я думаю что многие знают способ минификации html с помощью php:

```
<?php
function sanitize_output($buffer) {
    $search = array(
        '/\>[^\S ]+/s',  
        '/[^\S ]+\</s', 
        '/(\s)+/s'
    );
    $replace = array(
        '>',
        '<',
        '\\1'
    );
    $buffer = preg_replace($search, $replace, $buffer);
    return $buffer;
}
ob_start("sanitize_output");
?>
```

Пробовала этот метод на Bitrix - но код не как не воспринимается CMS. Есть ли вариант сжать html на Bitrix в 1 строку?

Comment: Ответил, но не понятно зачем так делать.  Gzip всё равно лучше жмёт

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так можно html сжать

```
// Удаляем лишние пробелы и пустые строки в html перед выводом пользователю
AddEventHandler("main", "OnEndBufferContent", "ChangeMyContent");

function ChangeMyContent(&$content){
    $content = sanitize_output($content);
}

function sanitize_output($buffer){
    $search = array(
        '/\>[^\S ]+/s', //strip whitespaces after tags, except space
        '/[^\S ]+\</s', //strip whitespaces before tags, except space
        '/(\s)+/s'  // shorten multiple whitespace sequences
    );
    $replace = array(
        '>',
        '<',
        '\\1'
    );

    $blocks = preg_split('/(<\/?pre[^>]*>)/', $buffer, null, 
                         PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
    $buffer = '';
    foreach($blocks as $i => $block){
      if($i % 4 == 2)
        $buffer .= $block; //break out <pre>...</pre> with \n's
      else 
        $buffer .= preg_replace($search, $replace, $block);
    }

    return $buffer;
}
```

А так еще и css сжать и вывести на радость Page Speed Insights

```
    AddEventHandler("main", "OnEndBufferContent", "deleteKernelCss");

     function deleteKernelCss(&$content) {
         global $USER, $APPLICATION;

         if ((is_object($USER) && $USER->IsAuthorized()) || strpos($APPLICATION->GetCurDir(), "/bitrix/") !== false || strpos($APPLICATION->GetCurDir(), "/peredvizhnie-stellazhi/")!== false)
             return;
         if ($APPLICATION->GetProperty("save_kernel") == "Y")
             return;

         $arPatternsToRemove = Array(
             '/<link.+?href=".+?kernel_main\/kernel_main\.css\?\d+"[^>]+>/',
         );

         $content = preg_replace($arPatternsToRemove, "", $content);
         $content = preg_replace("/\n{2,}/", "\n\n", $content);
     }

     AddEventHandler("main", "OnEndBufferContent", "includeCssInline");

     function includeCssInline(&$content) {
         global $USER, $APPLICATION;

         if ((is_object($USER) && $USER->IsAuthorized()) || strpos($APPLICATION->GetCurDir(), "/bitrix/") !== false)
             return;
         if ($APPLICATION->GetProperty("save_kernel") == "Y")
             return;

         preg_match('/<link.+?href="(\/bitrix\/cache\/css\/' . SITE_ID . '\/' . SITE_TEMPLATE_ID . '\/template_[^"]+)"[^>]+>/', $content, $arMatches);
         $sFilePath = "https://" . $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] . $arMatches[1];

         $obCache = new CPHPCache;
         $life_time = 0 * 60;

         if ($obCache->InitCache($life_time, $sFilePath, "/")) {
             $vars = $obCache->GetVars();
             $sIncludeCss = $vars["sIncludeCss"];
             $sIncludeCssClear = $vars["sIncludeCssClear"];
         } else {
             $sIncludeCss = file_get_contents($sFilePath);
             $sIncludeCssClear = compressCSS($sIncludeCss);
         }
         if (false) {
             ?><pre style="font-size:10px;line-height: 8px;">До: <?= strlen($sIncludeCss); ?></pre><?
             ?><pre style="font-size:10px;line-height: 8px;">После: <?= strlen($sIncludeCssClear); ?></pre><?
         }

         $content = str_replace($arMatches[0], "<style>$sIncludeCssClear</style>", $content);

         if ($obCache->StartDataCache()) {
             $obCache->EndDataCache(array(
                 "sIncludeCss" => $sIncludeCss,
                 "sIncludeCssClear" => $sIncludeCssClear,
             ));
         }
     }

     function compressCSS($css, $arOptions = Array()) {
         $sResult = $css;

         $sResult = preg_replace("/\/\*[^*]+\*\//", "", $sResult);      // comments
         $sResult = preg_replace("/\/\**\*\//", "", $sResult);         // comments
         $sResult = preg_replace("/\s*(:|,|;|{|}|\t)\s*/", "$1", $sResult);   // whitespaces
         $sResult = preg_replace("/(\t+|\s{2,})/", " ", $sResult);      // tabs and double whitespace
         $sResult = preg_replace("/(\s|:)([\-]{0,1}0px)\s/", " 0 ", $sResult);   // zeros
         $sResult = preg_replace("/#(\w){6};/", "#$1$1$1;", $sResult);      // #dddddd => #ddd

         return $sResult;
     }
```

Собрал куски на просторах) На авторство не претендую

Answer (score 3):

Возможно сделать через событие OnEndBufferContent

```
<?
AddEventHandler("main", "OnEndBufferContent", "ChangeMyContent");
function ChangeMyContent(&$content)
{
   $search = array(
        '/\>[^\S ]+/s',  
        '/[^\S ]+\</s', 
        '/(\s)+/s'
    );
    $replace = array(
        '>',
        '<',
        '\\1'
    );
    $content = preg_replace($search, $replace, $content);
}
?>
```

Код поместить в init.php.

Comment: Большое спасибо за помощь!

Comment: Есть не большой конфликт с админкой (там тоже минифицируется исходный код и из - за этого не работают некоторые функции) можно ли адаптировать код только для самого сайта (без админки) ?

Comment: Можно поставить условие в зависимости от SITE_ID или папки к которой идёт обращение

Comment: Спасибо за помощь